# Moshi: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I get the following error from `Moshi`: `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path`
This is my interface:

```
interface ApiService {
    @GET("movie/popular")
    suspend fun getTopRatedMovies(
        @Query("api_key") apiKey: String = BuildConfig.API_KEY,
        @Query("page") page: Int = 1
    ): List<TopRatedMovies>
```

data class

```
data class TopRatedMovies(
    @Json(name = "title") val title: String,
    @Json(name = "poster_path") val posterPath: String,
)
```

The response looks like this:
[image]

I know that there are some other questions with the same title but those didn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the function's return type (`List<TopRatedMovies>`), Moshi is expecting your API to return a list, but it's returning an object (`{"page": ..., "results": [...]}`) instead.

To handle this, you can create a `TopRatedMoviesPage` class like this:

```kotlin
data class TopRatedMoviesPage(
    @Json(name = "page") val page: Int,
    @Json(name = "results") val results: List<TopRatedMovies>,
)
```

And change your API definition to this:

```kotlin
@GET("movie/popular")
suspend fun getTopRatedMovies(
    @Query("api_key") apiKey: String = BuildConfig.API_KEY,
    @Query("page") page: Int = 1
): TopRatedMoviesPage
```

Comment: I've actually tried this before but I had to change some variable types for my LiveData. Anyway thanks a lot :)